# What should I do to how to fix android gradle error?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting an error while starting the application in android studio.

the error i got;
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexFileDependenciesTask$DexFileDependenciesWorkerAction
> Error while dexing.

Build Gradle app;

```
       plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'

id 'kotlin-kapt'
id("androidx.navigation.safeargs")
//id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
  }

android {
compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.maden.kuryeapp_v2"
    minSdk 23
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
sourceSets {
    main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    test.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}

buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
 }

productFlavors { }

    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
  }

}

 dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'


//Fragment
def nav_version = "2.3.5"
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")

//Picasso & Glide
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

//Coroutines
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.3")
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0")

//Others
implementation "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0"
implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'

implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.69'
implementation("com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android")

// RxJava
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'

// Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava3:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.5.0'


// Okhttp3 for the POST requests
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6'


//Google
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:17.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.auth0.android:jwtdecode:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:16.3.0'

implementation 'com.google.mlkit:language-id:16.1.1'
implementation 'net.gotev:speech:1.6.2'


implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: ['*mock*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'


implementation project(path: ':cropper')
implementation project(path: ':hbrecorder')
//implementation project(path: ':hbrecorder')


//tckk
implementation files('libs/ekds/tckkapi-operational-basic-2.13.1.jar')
implementation files('libs/ekds/tckkapi-interfaces-2.13.jar')
implementation files('libs/ekds/log4j-1.2.16.jar')

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs/esya', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation files('libs/pdf/ADDLTV.jar')



implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'org.jmrtd:jmrtd:0.7.18' // nfc kodu
implementation 'net.sf.scuba:scuba-sc-android:0.0.20'
implementation 'edu.ucar:jj2000:5.2'
implementation 'com.github.mhshams:jnbis:1.1.0'

//Camera
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha08'
 }
```

Build Gradle module;

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20-RC'

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files


    def nav_version = "2.3.5"
    classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
}
  }

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
```